# Distribute a stack of elements to a grid of elements?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, cs6, photoshop-scripting

I have dragged and dropped about 30 png's into a psd document so that they're each in a separate layer but laying on top of each other. I now wonder if anyone knows of a nifty trick or script to distribute these layers so that they're instead ordered in a grid in the document?

Comment: Photoshop has Align and Distribute function in CS6; have you tried those?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method is to place all the individual images into a folder on your desktop then use `File > Automate > Contact Sheet II...` within Photoshop to select the folder of images and have them arranged into a grid for a single document.

[image]

I believe the Contact Sheet script may be part of Adobe Bridge for CS6.

If you already have everything loaded as layers, you'll have to manually move, align, and distribute layers. There may be a script somewhere to do this for you, but since the nature of a grid is dependent upon the overall document size, I'm not sure you could find something pre-made which works as well as the Contact Sheet script.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Scott. I did try the Contact sheet II function. And it did distribute the image files on the PSD canvas as a grid. Unfortunately it did an absolutely terribly bad job. Resizing the images to maintain a consistent margin between the elements rather than adjusting the margin to maintain individual element resolution. I think this may be a good feature for some other future task I have, so I thank you for the tip and give you a +1, unfortunately however it doesn't solve the problem I have. Thanks.